# How to raise an HTTP exception from a subsequent command that failed in a saga in NestJS CQRS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, domain-driven-design, nestjs, cqrs

I'm using **NestJS CQRS** recipe in order to manage interactions between two entities: User and UserProfile. The architecture is an API Gateway NestJS server + a NestJS server for each microservice (User, UserProfile, etc.).

I have already set up basic interactions through User and UserProfile modules on API Gateway with their own sagas/events/commands:

- When a *user* is created, a *user profile* is created
- When the *user profile* creation fails, the **previously** created *user* is deleted

In details:

In User **module**, CreateUser **command** raises a UserCreated **event** that is intercepted by User **saga**, which will trigger CreateUserProfile **command** (from UserProfile **module**).

If the latter fails, a UserProfileFailedToCreate **event** is raised and intercepted by UserProfile **saga**, which will trigger DeleteUser **command** (from User **module**).

*Everything works fine.*

If the *CreateUser* command fails, I `resolve(Promise.reject(new HttpException(error, error.status))` which indicates to the end user that something went wrong during the user creation.

My problem is that I cannot replicate the same behavior for the *CreateUserProfile* command since the HTTP request promise has already been resolved from the first command, obviously.

So my question is: is there any way to make a command fail if a subsequent command fails in the saga? I understand that the HTTP request is totally disconnected from any subsequent commands triggered by a saga, but I want to know if anybody has already played with events or something else here to replicate this data flow?

One of the reasons I'm using CQRS, besides having a much cleaner code for data interactions among microservices, is to be able to rollback repositories actions in case any of the chained commands fails, which works fine. **But I need a way to indicate to the end user that the chain went through an issue and was rollbacked.**

*UserController.ts*

```
@Post('createUser')
async createUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<{user: IAuthUser, token: string}> {
  const { authUser } = await this.authService.createAuthUser(createUserDto);
  // this is executed after resolve() in CreateUserCommand
  return {user: authUser, token: this.authService.createAccessTokenFromUser(authUser)};
}
```

*UserService.ts*

```
async createAuthUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<{authUser: IAuthUser}> {
  return await this.commandBus
    .execute(new CreateAuthUserCommand(createUserDto))
    .catch(error => { throw new HttpException(error, error.status); });
}
```

*CreateUserCommand.ts*

```
async execute(command: CreateAuthUserCommand, resolve: (value?) => void) {
    const { createUserDto } = command;
    const createAuthUserDto: CreateAuthUserDto = {
      email: createUserDto.email,
      password: createUserDto.password,
      phoneNumber: createUserDto.phoneNumber,
    };

    try {
      const user = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(
        await this.client
          .send<IAuthUser>({ cmd: 'createAuthUser' }, createAuthUserDto)
          .toPromise()
          .then((dbUser: IAuthUser) => {
            const {password, passwordConfirm, ...publicUser} = Object.assign(dbUser, createUserDto);
            return new AuthUser(publicUser);
          }),
      );
      user.notifyCreated();
      user.commit();
      resolve(user); // <== This makes the HTTP request return its reponse
    } catch (error) {
      resolve(Promise.reject(error));
    }
  }
```

*UserSagas.ts*

```
authUserCreated = (event$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> => {
    return event$
      .ofType(AuthUserCreatedEvent)
      .pipe(
        map(event => {
          const createUserProfileDto: CreateUserProfileDto = {
            avatarUrl: '',
            firstName: event.authUser.firstName,
            lastName: event.authUser.lastName,
            nationality: '',
            userId: event.authUser.id,
            username: event.authUser.username,
          };
          return new CreateUserProfileCommand(createUserProfileDto);
        }),
      );
  }
```

*CreateUserProfileCommand.ts*

```
async execute(command: CreateUserProfileCommand, resolve: (value?) => void) {
    const { createUserProfileDto } = command;

    try {
      const userProfile = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(
        await this.client
          .send<IUserProfile>({ cmd: 'createUserProfile' }, createUserProfileDto)
          .toPromise()
          .then((dbUserProfile: IUserProfile) => new UserProfile(dbUserProfile)),
      );
      userProfile.notifyCreated();
      userProfile.commit();
      resolve(userProfile);
    } catch (error) {
      const userProfile = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(new UserProfile({id: createUserProfileDto.userId} as IUserProfile));
      userProfile.notifyFailedToCreate();
      userProfile.commit();
      resolve(Promise.reject(new HttpException(error, 500)).catch(() => {}));
    }
  }
```

*UserProfileSagas.ts*

```
userProfileFailedToCreate = (event$: EventObservable<any>): Observable<ICommand> => {
    return event$
      .ofType(UserProfileFailedToCreateEvent)
      .pipe(
        map(event => {
          return new DeleteAuthUserCommand(event.userProfile);
        }),
      );
  }
```

*DeleteUserCommand.ts*

```
async execute(command: DeleteAuthUserCommand, resolve: (value?) => void) {
    const { deleteAuthUserDto } = command;

    try {
      const user = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(
        await this.client
          .send<IAuthUser>({ cmd: 'deleteAuthUser' }, deleteAuthUserDto)
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => new AuthUser({} as IAuthUser)),
      );
      user.notifyDeleted();
      user.commit();
      resolve(user);
    } catch (error) {
      resolve(Promise.reject(new HttpException(error, error.status)).catch(() => {}));
    }
  }
```

Comment: without actual code, it's not easy to see where you've done something wrong - perhaps you've got a catch that "handles" the error and therefore the error doesn't "chain" down

Comment: Why don't you try to create the profile first and then the user? In other words, you send the commands in reverse order

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added the code.

But just to be sure I didn't get it wrong: the fact that subsequent commands are triggered by events means that any subsequent related errors **cannot** chain down to the initial HTTP request, right? 

Basically my point in this issue was not that there was a catch issue somewhere, but rather that it is technically not possible to chain subsequent errors, thus I was asking for ideas to get that done in some other way...

But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu What's the point of reversing? I would have to consider user creation failure and then delete the previously created user profile. Plus, user profile contains a foreign key to userId.

Comment: @S.Dan I see, I'm not sure how this framework works as I never used it, I use my own framework. So, profile creation is run in another process/machine?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes, it's running in a different pod in AKS

Comment: @JaromandaX Any idea with the added code?

Comment: From NestJs Document, you must use asynchronous for handle error in event handle or saga such as: websocket, SSE. See more at here https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs#events

Answer (score 2):

In DDD terms your creation of `User` and `UserProfile` constitutes a *business transaction* - a group of business operations/rules that must be consistent - that [spans multiple microservices](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

In that case returning the database `User` before the `UserProfile` has been created means you return data in an inconsistent state. This is not necessarily wrong, but you should handle this appropriately in the client if you do it like that.

I see three possible ways to deal with this scenario:

1. You let the Sagas run until they have executed commands that indicate the business transaction has ended, only then resolve an outcome for the client indicating either success or failure (e.g. in error details you can report which steps succeeded and which did not). So you do not yet resolve in `CreateAuthUserCommand`.
2. If it can take a long time for the `UserProfile` to be created (it could even have to be manually validated by a Moderator) then you might want to resolve the `User` in `CreateAuthUserCommand` and then subsequently have the client subscribe to UserProfile-related events. You need a mechanism for that, but it decouples the client from the running transaction, and it can do other stuff.
3. Alternatively you could break up the business transaction into two parts for which the client sends separate requests: one creates/returns the authenticated `User`, and the other returns the created `UserProfile`. Though it seems that `User` + `UserProfile` belong to the same bounded context, the fact that they reside in two different microservices may indicate they are not (in this case I think the first microservice really is for Authentication and the other for UserProfiles which indicate different bounded contexts to me). Best-practice is to have a microservice implement their own encapsulated bounded context.

*(Note: Answered an old question in hopes it is informative to others)*